# Arrow function syntax with assignment ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

Quick question, I'm new with es6 syntax and typscript and I just found this code in my current ng2 project:

```
this.contextActions.getCurrentContextAction().subscribe((link) => this.currentAction = link);
```

Just to be clear if I understand it correctly.

The function subscribe takes as argument a function which takes a parameter (link) and it assigns the input parameter to the current action, and it returns the result of this assigment?

Is it correct my understanding?
What is actually what this arrow function returns? The result of the assigment? 
An assigment does not return anything right?

Please clrify this to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it correct my understanding? What is actually what this arrow function returns? The result of the assigment?

Yes. It may not be significant depending on what the code calling it does with the return value.

> An assigment does not return anything right?

It evaluates as the assigned value.

```js
var bar, foo;
foo = (bar = 1);
console.log("Foo is " + foo);
```

Comment: Some small addition to explanation. This is `arrow function` which implicit define inline function and `return` always result of line. Link to documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

> An assignment does not return anything right?

Wrong, the value of an assignment is the value that is assigned:

```js
var a;
console.log(a = 5);
```

This is why you can do things like this:

```js
var a, b, c;
console.log(a = b = c = 5); // all have the value 5
```

So the arrow function returns its parameter, `link`. I don't know if the `subscribe` function does something with the returned value. Presumably not.

The rest of your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is effectively the same as:

```
var _this = this;
this.contextActions
  .getCurrentContextAction()
  .subscribe(function(link) { 
    return _this.currentAction = link
  });
```

Subscribe accepts a function that takes a single parameter (link) that will be internally called by subscribe at a certain stage.

In this context, link is an internally generated variable that is given to the function you are passing in as input. You could alternatively do the following:

```
function myFunction(link) { 
  return _this.currentAction = link
}

var _this = this;
this.contextActions
  .getCurrentContextAction()
  .subscribe(myFunction);
```

The arrow function will **assign the value** given to your callback to `this.currentAction` and then **return the value** in a single statement.

E.g.:

```
var a, b, c;

console.log(a = 5); // Logs out 5

function test() {
  return b = 6;
}

c = test();
console.log(b); // Logs out 6
console.log(c); // Logs out 6
```

Comment: Anyone explain the downvote here? This is the only one that actually explains why arrow functions are _different_ than normal functions. They don't have a context (the `this`) or `arguments` variable inherent in their scope like normal functions do.

Answer (score -3):

If you did not use `=>` it would look like this

```
var _that = this;
.subscribe(function(link){
   return _that.currentAction = link;
}
```

It returns the assigned value.

See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

> (param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }
> (param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
> // equivalent to: (param1, param2, …, paramN) => { return expression; }
>
> // Parentheses are optional when there's only one parameter name:
> (singleParam) => { statements }
> singleParam => { statements }

Comment: It wouldn't. Arrow functions and function expressions get different values of `this`. You've also ignored the question about what returning an assignment expression means.

Comment: @Quentin Fixed it.

Comment: Still no explanation as to what the significance of `return _that.currentAction = link` is.

Comment: @Quentin It returns the assigned value. What else needs to be explained there?

Comment: Nothing … but your answer doesn't say that and its the point the question focuses on!

Comment: @Quentin Think `return anything` is pretty much self explanatory since they keyword did not appear in the arrow function.

Comment: The question clearly indicates that the OP knows that the `()=>expression` form of an arrow function returns the result of evaluating the expression. They are asking what the result of evaluating the assignment expression is.

Comment: @Quentin added.

Answer (score -4):

A good way to test this is to open up a browser and see what it does. Let's see what happens in Chrome Dev tools when console log an assignment.

```
var someNum = 5;

console.log(someNum = 20);
```

> 20